Characterization of Commutativity Without Twist Maps?
I ran into some interesting statements characterizing (co)commutativity:
Recall that a group object in $\mathsf{Grp}$ is precisely an abelian group. This amounts to requiring the multiplication map $\mu: G \times G \to G$ be a group homomorphism. In Sweedler's Hopf Algebra I also see that a coalgebra $C$ is cocommutative iff the comultiplication $\Delta: C \to C \otimes C$ is a coalgebra homomorphism. This characterization then behaves well on binary and cobinary operations.
So, to what extent can this be generalized? Are there any examples? I know that this fails at lie algebras as there are no easy lie algebra structures on the tensor product of lie algebras..
